# Sonatype Nexus 3 HTTPS step by step?

Tags: https, nexus

Всем привет. Дорогие друзья, помогите пожалуйста настроить Nexus с использованием прокси Https? Не могу понять, как настроить nginx или apache для Nexus для работы с портом 80 на 443? Теперь наш сервер Nexus работает на 80 портах, а не на apache или nginx. Я видел много руководств по этому поводу, но не могу полностью понять ...

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/configuring-ssl#ConfiguringSSL-UsingAReverseProxyServer

Может быть, кто-нибудь может немного пошагово рассказать, как я могу просто настроить https с помощью Nexus?

Спасибо!!! 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего сам себе отвечаю на вопросы: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465768-SSL-Certificate-Guide и https://www.coveros.com/ssl-on-nexus-3/